# jQuery Clone Clear Text Field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, clone

I am trying to get the friend fields (name + email) to repeat when you click "add another friend".
Every time I try to clone the fields it includes the text inside the fields which I dont want!
Has anybody got any ideas?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJW6w/5/)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the fields  `value=''` after you take the values from them

Answer (score 0):

Bind a click event handler to the "add another friend" `<div>` element. In that event handler, you want to append another row of form elements to the `<p>` element.

HTML:

```
<p id="friendlist">Friend 1 Name:
    <input type="text" name="friend_name[]" class="friendid">
    Friend 1 Email:
    <input type="text" name="friend_email[]" class="friendid"/></p>

<div id="addanother">add another friend</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

Your jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var nextIndex = 2;

    $("#addanother").click(function() {
        var html = '<br />Friend ' + nextIndex + 'Name:';
        html += '<input type="text" name="friend_name[]" class="friendid" />'
        html += 'Friend ' + nextIndex + 'Email:';
        html += '<input type="text" name="friend_email[]" class="friendid" />';
        $("#friendlist").append($(html));
        nextIndex++;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYS2g/)